# How do I know if a live tile update "failed"?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, live-tile

I am using live tiles for my application. The XML used to update the tile is dynamically generated and *sometimes* the update fails because of the content (I don't control what is being displayed in the live tile, I get that from webservices).

I used to use the API to build the notification through instances of `TileWideSmallImageAndText02` for example but I now need to build the XML directly in the code. A simplified version of my code:

```
string tileXml = "<tile><visual><binding template=\"TileWideSmallImageAndText02\">" +
                                 "<image id=\"1\" src=\"" + image + "\" alt=\"alt text\"/>"
                                 + "<text id=\"1\">" + title + "</text>"
                                + "<text id=\"2\">" + date + "</text>"
                                 + "<text id=\"3\">" + time + "</text>"
                                + "<text id=\"4\">" + length + "</text>"
                             + "</binding>"
                             + "</visual>"
                            + "</tile>";
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument tileDOM = 
                                    new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
tileDOM.LoadXml(tileXml);
TileNotification tile = new TileNotification(tileDOM);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile);
```

Now as I said before, the notification may fail ; and by failing I mean the tile is not being updated. It looks like that if I send whatever XML content I want to the `Update`, no exception will be raised and I will never know if the live tile worked or not.

What would be a good way to intercept the failure if I receive badly formatted data from the webservices I use?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there isn't a way to check whether an update failed.

You can protect yourself to some extent by using a library ([PushSharp](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PushSharp) maybe) or sanitizing the data you retrieve from your webservices before you pass it on to the Notification service.